# Retrieve a field from the model in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

I have assigned the Post.first to post. I am trying to retrieve one of the fields say. title, or content.
post.title gives nil. I am suppose to get "our first post". What did i do wrong here?

Below is the content of the Post model.

[image]

Comment: Show your `Post` model source.

Comment: I meant source. `app/models/post.rb` file content.

Comment: @yogi what you were asked was to show your `app/models/post.rb` file

Comment: Have updated the post with the model source. I am able to get retrieve the attributes when i comment the "attr :title, :content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some `attr_accessor` in your `Post` model.

ActiveRecord creates the setters and getters for you (for all the columns in your posts table), so you don't have to define them. In fact, if you define them, what you are doing is to override the ActiveRecord methods.